# C# Printing overlaps after submiting the form multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, printing

So I have a program which I want to create as a POS Program for restaurant (practicing). The main problem is I add everything product from my program and fill out the details that I want (Name, Address etc. for delivery purposes). For the first time everything goes pretty well and it prints out a nice looking receipt but after that. The printPage method get called for the amount of times which I used it before like a queue which remembers all of the past printings and at the end it is overlapping.

Here is the code for my Printer class. Which I call from my **Form1.cs**

```
  //Printer.cs
  public class Printer
    {
        public Printer(List<Stuff> _StuffList, OtherClass _OtherClass)
        {
            this._StuffList = _StuffList;
            this._OtherClass = _OtherClass;

        }
    public void printPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    //The other stuff below is just receipt drawing.
    }
```

And Here is my Form1.cs

```
//Form1.cs
Printer printer;
private void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            OtherClass = new _OtherClass(data_from_textbox here));
            printer = new Printer(StuffList, OtherClass);
            printReceipt(printer);
            StuffList.Clear();
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            OtherClass.Clear();
            //reset TextBox & Labels
            label.Text = "";
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
private static String FILE = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\FILE.txt"; 
        private void printReceipt(Printer printer)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            stringToPrint = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T20III Receipt";
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
            printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printer.printPage);
            printDocument.Print();
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You're adding a new PrintPage event handler each time you press that Button. All delegates are called when you start the printing process

Comment: Oh okay. I try to make that the program only have 1 going on. I'll check back with the resutls as soon as i can.